# Search Multiple Queries from List in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, linked-data

I want to find sales data for a set of 300 addresses using the UK Land Registry database. The database permits SPARQL queries, however I am completely new to SPARQL, and do not know how to make multiple queries at once (e.g. search for 300 addresses in one SPARQL query).

[This is an example land registry query](http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/hpi/qonsole?q=PREFIX%20%20text:%20%3Chttp://jena.apache.org/text%23%3E%0APREFIX%20%20ppd:%20%20%3Chttp://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/%3E%0APREFIX%20%20lrcommon:%20%3Chttp://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%20?item%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20?ppd_hasTransaction%20?ppd_pricePaid%20?ppd_transactionCategory%20?ppd_transactionDate%20?ppd_transactionId%20?ppd_estateType%20?ppd_newBuild%20?ppd_propertyAddressCounty%20?ppd_propertyAddressDistrict%20?ppd_propertyAddressLocality%20?ppd_propertyAddressPaon%20?ppd_propertyAddressPostcode%20?ppd_propertyAddressSaon%20?ppd_propertyAddressStreet%20?ppd_propertyAddressTown%20?ppd_propertyType%20?ppd_recordStatus%0AWHERE%0A%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20text:query%20_:b0%20.%0A%20%20%20%20_:b0%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23first%3E%20%22paon:%20(%2012%20)%20%20AND%20street:%20(%20PATTINSON%20AND%20DRIVE%20)%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20_:b0%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23rest%3E%20_:b1%20.%0A%20%20%20%20_:b1%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23first%3E%203000000%20.%0A%20%20%20%20_:b1%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23rest%3E%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23nil%3E%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?item%20ppd:propertyAddress%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?item%20ppd:hasTransaction%20?ppd_hasTransaction%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?item%20ppd:pricePaid%20?ppd_pricePaid%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?item%20ppd:transactionCategory%20?ppd_transactionCategory%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?item%20ppd:transactionDate%20?ppd_transactionDate%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?item%20ppd:transactionId%20?ppd_transactionId%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?item%20ppd:estateType%20?ppd_estateType%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?item%20ppd:newBuild%20?ppd_newBuild%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:county%20?ppd_propertyAddressCounty%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:district%20?ppd_propertyAddressDistrict%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:locality%20?ppd_propertyAddressLocality%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:paon%20?ppd_propertyAddressPaon%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:postcode%20?ppd_propertyAddressPostcode%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:saon%20?ppd_propertyAddressSaon%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:street%20?ppd_propertyAddressStreet%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?ppd_propertyAddress%20lrcommon:town%20?ppd_propertyAddressTown%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?item%20ppd:propertyType%20?ppd_propertyType%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20?item%20ppd:recordStatus%20?ppd_recordStatus%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0ALIMIT%20%20%20100%0A) for a single address.

So I have two questions:

1) How can I search for multiple addresses in one query?

2) Is there a way to connect a database list of addresses to automate the query?

Help and direction will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the example query, the first five triple patterns in the `WHERE` clause ties the result to a specific result.  Delete these or comment out with a `#` and you will get a list of all addresses known to the chosen SPARQL endpoint:

```
prefix ...

SELECT  ?item ?ppd_propertyAddress ?ppd_hasTransaction ?ppd_pricePaid ? ppd_transactionCategory ?ppd_transactionDate ?ppd_transactionId ?ppd_estateType    ?ppd_newBuild ?ppd_propertyAddressCounty ?ppd_propertyAddressDistrict ?ppd_propertyAddressLocality ?ppd_propertyAddressPaon ?ppd_propertyAddressPostcode ?ppd_propertyAddressSaon ?ppd_propertyAddressStreet ?ppd_propertyAddressTown ?ppd_propertyType ?ppd_recordStatus
WHERE
{ #?ppd_propertyAddress text:query _:b0 .
  #_:b0 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#first> "paon: ( 12 )  AND street: ( PATTINSON AND DRIVE )" .
  #_:b0 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#rest> _:b1 .
  #_:b1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#first> 3000000 .
  #_:b1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#rest> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil> .
  ?item ppd:propertyAddress ?ppd_propertyAddress .
  ?item ppd:hasTransaction ?ppd_hasTransaction .
  ?item ppd:pricePaid ?ppd_pricePaid .
  ?item ppd:transactionCategory ?ppd_transactionCategory .
  ?item ppd:transactionDate ?ppd_transactionDate .
  ?item ppd:transactionId ?ppd_transactionId
  OPTIONAL
  { ?item ppd:estateType ?ppd_estateType }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?item ppd:newBuild ?ppd_newBuild }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:county ?ppd_propertyAddressCounty }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:district ?ppd_propertyAddressDistrict }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:locality ?ppd_propertyAddressLocality }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:paon ?ppd_propertyAddressPaon }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:postcode ?ppd_propertyAddressPostcode }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:saon ?ppd_propertyAddressSaon }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:street ?ppd_propertyAddressStreet }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?ppd_propertyAddress lrcommon:town ?ppd_propertyAddressTown }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?item ppd:propertyType ?ppd_propertyType }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?item ppd:recordStatus ?ppd_recordStatus }
}
LIMIT   100
```

The second question is unclear and perhaps resolved by the above?  I.e. you don't need to submit multiple queries.

If you want to query for a specific list of addresses, then you could use a SPARQL `VALUES` expression, see [VALUES: Providing inline data](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#inline-data).  A starting point may be the following (by inspection only - you'd have to check this against the data):

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
   VALUES ?addr {"address1" "paon: ( 12 )  AND street: ( PATTINSON AND DRIVE )" ...}
   ?ppd_propertyAddress text:query _:b0 .
   _:b0 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#first> ?addr .
   ?item ppd:propertyAddress ?ppd_propertyAddress .

   ...
}
```

Note that `VALUES` binds `?addr` to each string in the list between the braces in the `VALUES` clause. `?addr` is then used in the triple pattern in place of the address in the original query.

Comment: I don't see which lines you mean by "the first five triple patterns in the `WHERE` clause". Can you provide an example with them commented out? It would also be very useful to see the implementation of the `VALUES` expression. To be clear, I want to submit a single query that returns the results for 300 addresses, which I currently have in a CSV.

Comment: Added to the answer.  For `VALUES` I have a provided a link that has examples.

Comment: I cannot implement your code without it breaking, and I do not know how to implement the `VALUES` expression appropriately, querying two separate addresses.